# What did the Predator say to Dutch during the final fight scene?

Tags: dialogue, predator

In *Predator* (1987), during the final fight scene, Dutch defeats the Predator, after hitting the Predator with a big rock, and then stops.

Then he asks the Predator,

> "What the hell are you?"

Then the Predator replies, but it's not clear to me what was actually said.

Does anybody else know what it says?

Comment: Relevant youtube link: https://youtu.be/EnoNpqAW2qE?t=1m10s

Comment: related:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145743/are-the-predators-last-words-to-dutch-a-mimic-or-a-question

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Predator was just mimicking back what he said. Just his way of taunting before he hit the self destruct.

Even [Wikipedia synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predator_(film)#Plot) describes it quite well:

> As the creature lies dying, Dutch asks in disgust, "What the hell are you?". The alien simply repeats the question in garbled English before activating a self-destruct device, laughing maniacally as the countdown begins.

Comment: I always thought it said 'I am what you are'

Comment: I never considered it a taunt. I always thought the Predator could understand human language to an extent and it was a serious question back since this puny human had out predator'd him.

Comment: I always thought the Predator said *"I am Hell...."*

Comment: related:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/145751/68218

Answer (score 20):

After reading the script, I think the predator does ask "who the hell are you?' but I take it not just as mimicking, but as really asking the question. Asking Dutch:

1. Who is it that can kill a predator
2. Aren't they really both the same kind of creature, that is, a killing, hunting machine?

Comment: I agree with this. If you listen to [the fragment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnoNpqAW2qE&feature=youtu.be&t=1m10s), you can hear that the Predator says, "what the hell are _you_?", stressing the final word.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of audio it just seems like the predator repeats "what the hell are you?" back.

I've always taken it to be a sort of resigned snorting retort, not straight disrespect. Along the lines of "huh, how could I let one of YOU best me?"/"Are you different or did I done goof up?"

The '87 predator seemed to be a fairly juvenile sloppy hunter, relying more on the advanced gear and straight physical prowess.
We'd make good blood for a new hunter but even with a gun I doubt humans are expected to be close to Xenomorph level prey.